# What is the preferred GRE Writing score for MS/CS student?

Tags: graduate-admissions, gre

I am planing to apply to study in graduate school, major in *computer science/engineering*. I just took a GRE test, this is my 1st time, and the result is pretty...not so good :(

Most schools, the science or engineering related program, reveals the average or preferred GRE scores for *quantitative* and *verbal* sections for admitted students. But it seems they don't care about the score of *Analytic Writing* section. Really?

To be honest, my writing score really bumped this time. I want to know if there's a preferred score range for this section.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's a reason it's not listed--there is no preferred score, it doesn't really matter.  I am not an expert, but I feel like the writing score is something that can only hurt you, not something that can help you, at least with respect to science or engineering graduate programs.

More concretely, I can see a very low score preventing you from getting into a program, but I highly doubt the admissions committee saying: "Well, he got a great score on the writing section, that really differentiates him from other applicants; let's admit him."

For a foreign student or non-native speaker, doing well in the writing section probably carries a little more weight than it does for native speakers; nonetheless, I believe that the above still holds.

Answer (score 2):

According to my experience:

The GRE scores are just initial cut-offs.

Analytical writing usually requires a minimum score of 3 that's it. But this is true for most of the universities there may be some exceptions to the rule obviously.

```
Scores 3 and 2.5
Displays some competence in analytical writing, although the writing is flawed in at least one of the following ways: limited analysis or development; weak organization; weak control of sentence structure or language usage, with errors that often result in vagueness or lack of clarity.
```