# How relevant is the GRE essay score for masters applications in science and engineering?

Tags: mathematics, computer-science, gre

I wish to apply for masters in Mathematics or Computer science after my undergraduate. I have a good GRE score of 332/340, but my essay score is just 3.5/6. I wanted to know how relevant is the essay score for
technical fields?

Is  it relevant enough that I should consider giving the GRE again?

I have heard and read that the GRE score is only used for 'sorting' the students. I just wanted to make sure that the essay score doesn't sort me out of the admissions process.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://academia.stackexchange.com/q/14345/19607

Comment: Voting to close as a duplicate of the above linked question.